# Next.js chunking and lazy loading

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm quite new to Next.js. I have a Next.js app which uses React and a headless CMS for building the page up. A editor in the CMS can move components around, add/remove components etc. My question is, is it possible to use code splitting and lazy loading so that only the components in the page are included in the bundle, and are lazy loaded depending how far the user scrolls on the page? I know this can be done if I don't have a CMS and run the build, but if a CMS editor changes components, surely the app needs to be re-build to know how to chunk correctly? Can this be done with incremental static site re-generation?

Thanks in advance.